# Difficulty Validating Output in Quantum Computing Simulation

Tags: node.js, socket.io, quantum-computing

I'm currently working on a quantum computing simulation using JavaScript and Socket.IO. The simulation involves a set of qubits represented as bits, and the goal is to calculate the percentage of matches in different groups.

Each group has a predefined size, and a match occurs when adjacent qubits share the same value (either both 0 or both 1). The simulation also takes into account a controller setting, affecting when points are added based on matches.

My objective is to achieve specific target percentages for each group: A (25%), B (25%), C (25%), and D (25%) of the total qubits. The percentage represents the proportion of matches within each group.

I'm encountering challenges in accurately calculating these percentages, and the output seems inconsistent. I'm seeking assistance in reviewing and potentially refining the relevant sections of my JavaScript code to ensure that the output aligns with the desired target percentages.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

// Number of qubits
let num_qubits = 20; // You can change this number

// Initialize classical bits
let bits = Array.from({ length: num_qubits }, () => 0);

// Initialize score
let score = 0;

// Controller setting
let controllerSetting = 0;

// Function to count matches in a group
function countMatchesInGroup(...qubitIndices) {
    return qubitIndices.reduce((count, idx) => (bits[idx] === 1 ? count + 1 : count), 0);
}

function updateBits() {
    // Simulate superposition with classical probabilities for each qubit
    const probabilities = Array.from({ length: num_qubits }, () => 0.5);

    // Save current states for comparison
    const previousStates = [...bits];

    // Randomly choose states based on probabilities
    bits = probabilities.map(prob => (Math.random() < prob ? 0 : 1));

    // Calculate the group size based on the controller setting
    const groupSize = Math.floor(num_qubits / 4);

    // Compare current states with previous states and update score
    for (let i = 0; i < num_qubits - groupSize + 1; i += groupSize) {
        let match = true;

        for (let j = 0; j < groupSize - 1; j++) {
            const currentBit = bits[i + j];
            const nextBit = bits[i + j + 1];
            const previousBit = previousStates[i + j];
            const previousNextBit = previousStates[i + j + 1];

            // Check the matching condition for the specific controller setting
            if (controllerSetting === 0 && (currentBit !== previousBit || nextBit !== previousNextBit)) {
                match = false;
                break;
            } else if (controllerSetting > 0 && currentBit !== previousBit) {
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (match) {
            score += 1;
        }
    }

    // Calculate the percentage of matches for each group
    const percentA = ((countMatchesInGroup(...Array.from({ length: num_qubits / 4 }, (_, j) => j)) / (num_qubits / 4)) * 100).toFixed(2);
    const percentB = ((countMatchesInGroup(...Array.from({ length: num_qubits / 4 }, (_, j) => j + num_qubits / 4)) / (num_qubits / 4)) * 100).toFixed(2);
    const percentC = ((countMatchesInGroup(...Array.from({ length: num_qubits / 4 }, (_, j) => j + 2 * num_qubits / 4)) / (num_qubits / 4)) * 100).toFixed(2);
    const percentD = ((countMatchesInGroup(...Array.from({ length: num_qubits / 4 }, (_, j) => j + 3 * num_qubits / 4)) / (num_qubits / 4)) * 100).toFixed(2);
    // Output the letter along with the score
    console.log(`Score: ${score}, Output: A${percentA}%, B${percentB}%, C${percentC}%, D${percentD}%`);

    return bits;
}

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    // Send initial parameters to the client
    socket.emit('initialParams', { num_qubits, controllerSetting });

    // Listen for controller setting changes from the client
    socket.on('changeControllerSetting', (newSetting) => {
        controllerSetting = newSetting;
        io.emit('controllerSettingChanged', controllerSetting);
    });

    // Listen for number of qubits changes from the client
    socket.on('changeNumQubits', (newNumQubits) => {
        num_qubits = newNumQubits;
        io.emit('numQubitsChanged', num_qubits);
    });

    // Listen for simulation updates from the client
    socket.on('requestSimulationUpdate', () => {
        const updatedBits = updateBits();
        io.emit('simulationUpdated', { bits: updatedBits, score });
    });
});

// Start the server
const PORT = 3000;
http.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

this is another way i tried it with just using half A and half B and with the output being A or B for most matches

```
// Number of qubits
let num_qubits = 10;

// Initialize classical bits
let bits = Array.from({ length: num_qubits }, () => 0);

// Initialize score
let score = 0;

// Controller setting
let controllerSetting = 0;

function updateBits() {
    // Simulate superposition with classical probabilities for each qubit
    const probabilities = Array.from({ length: num_qubits }, () => 0.5);

    // Save current states for comparison
    const previousStates = [...bits];

    // Randomly choose states based on probabilities
    bits = probabilities.map(prob => (Math.random() < prob ? 0 : 1));

    // Calculate the group size based on the controller setting
    const groupSize = 2 + (controllerSetting * 2);

    // Compare current states with previous states and update score
    for (let i = 0; i < num_qubits - groupSize + 1; i += groupSize) {
        let match = true;

        for (let j = 0; j < groupSize - 1; j++) {
            const currentBit = bits[i + j];
            const nextBit = bits[i + j + 1];
            const previousBit = previousStates[i + j];
            const previousNextBit = previousStates[i + j + 1];

            // Check the matching condition for the specific controller setting
            if (controllerSetting === 0 && (currentBit !== previousBit || nextBit !== previousNextBit)) {
                match = false;
                break;
            } else if (controllerSetting > 0 && currentBit !== previousBit) {
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (match) {
            score += 1;
        }
    }

    // Calculate the number of matches in the first and second halves
    const matchesInA = Math.floor(score / 2);
    const matchesInB = score - matchesInA;

    // Determine the output letter based on the distribution of matches
    const outputLetter = matchesInA % 2 === 0 ? 'A' : 'B';

    // Output the letter along with the score
    console.log(`Score: ${score}, Output: ${outputLetter}`);

    return bits;
}
```